# Array inside an Object with Dynamic Key in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

Given, I have an array

```
var myKey = "myObjectKey";
var anArray = ["apple", "balloon", "dog", "cat"];

anArray.map(function(thing) {
  store.dispatch(Object.assign({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: thing, key: myKey}));
});
```

How do I get the following output?

```
store.getState();
# Object: {myObjectKey: ["apple", "balloon", "dog", "cat"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Just pass the `object` to the dispatch. It will be handelled in the reducer

```
var myKey = "myObjectKey";
var anArray = ["apple", "balloon", "dog", "cat"];

  store.dispatch({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: { [myKey]: anArray} })
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! However, I can access it via store.getState[0]["payload"][myKey], not store.getState()[myKey].